# Why are the leaves on my tomato seedling turning brown?

Tags: leaves, tomatoes

This is the 2nd year I have grown tomatoes. I am a young gardener, with a balcony garden in pots. Last year went fantastic and produced many tomatoes. This year I  have 6 plants I started from seed indoors. Three Pomodoro San Marzano Tomatoes, and three Pomodoro Scatolone tomatoes. They are all planted in plastic pots with store-bought potting soil.

I just transferred them to the pots and put them on my deck a few days ago and today I noticed the leaves were changing color. I am completely new to this and don't know what it is or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated! (My balcony garden is the only place it can be, I live in an apartment but sunshine is not an issue)

[image: plant leaves]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the plants are getting sunburned. You need to expose plants to sunlight gradually which is known as hardening off. See this info from Burpee: http://www.burpee.com/gardenadvicecenter/areas-of-interest/seed-starting/hardening-off-your-seedlings/article10355.html